# Unsung Hero Query

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer

I have taken a look at my stats on

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/345/how-unsung-am-i

The results in that query don't seem to tally with my own counting. The query says I have 23 accepted of which 16 are scored and 7 unscored.

If I count my own answers on my profile page, I see.
37 accepted answers, of which 27 are scored and 10 are unscored.

Why would these figures not tally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data explorer queries the monthly data dumps, which are updated for the previous month around the 5th-10th.  Since it's the 29th of November today the data found there is 29 days out of date.

There was talk a while ago of increasing the frequency of the dumps, although I don't know if that's still part of the plan.

Comment: I believe it's still part of the plan, but odata will have to move to SO servers before that's a practical thing to do (Azure bulk data upload is a nightmare), not sure when that's slated.

Comment: Is it refreshed monthly? It's already December 1st, and its still not updated.

Comment: @yahelc: like I said in my answer, it's usually updated around 5th-10th

Comment: clearly, I need to consider reading. Sorry!